# Break an (accidental) endless loop in a swift playground

Tags: xcode, freeze, swift-playground

while playing around in a swift playground (what's in a name), I accidentally entered an endless loop, such like this one :

```
var l = 3
while (l > 2) {
  println(l)
  l++
}
```

this causes the playground to endlessly print to the console, upon which Xcode gets stuck

The only way I found was to kill Xcode through the terminal window, however I would expect there is some more elegant way to 'stop' the playground from executing?

Comment: [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: thanks ... I just filed a bug report ... my first one :-) Thought there would be some keyboard command to 'break' ? like CTRL-C on a PC ?

Answer (score 6):

Playground is operating exactly as designed, but it really should have a means of instantly halting execution while editing code. I have entered endless loops in mid-edit the same way as you, and it usually happens while editing the conditions in a for or while loop.

I work around this limitation by deliberately typing a few characters of gibberish on the line I am editing, or on a separate line if editing multiple lines. Playground will choke on the gibberish and stop executing the code. When I finish editing, I remove the gibberish so that Playground can execute the code once again.

For example, if I want to edit this line:

```
for var j=0;j<10000000;j=j+1000 {
```

I will first add gibberish to the end:

```
for var j=0;j<10000000;j=j+1000 { adsklfasd
```

then I will make my edits:

```
for var j=0;j<500;j=j+10 { adsklfasd
```

then i will remove the gibberish, leaving behind only the good code:

```
for var j=0;j<500;j=j+10 {
```

Playground won't execute as long as the adsklfasd is in there.

The gibberish doesn't have to go at the end of the for statement; you could put it on a separate line, if you prefer.

It's not an elegant solution, but it's fast and easy and it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed, its really surprising that there is no Control-C equivalent to force a break.

Comment: This does not work in the latest Xcode 7 beta, just a heads up.

Answer (score 2):

This is Xcode 8.3.3. I did not check previous versions.

While the playground is running, the source code is still editable.
Just change the loop, type in a command, for example **break** into the code, inside the loop. This is interpreted code not compiled code so it will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to halt my loop by typing the iteration variable setting (that would stop the loop) somewhere else like in a text editor then right click pasting the text into the loop.

In your case, right-click pasting l = 0  right before the last bracket should work.